# Dimension of subspace in $\Bbb R^6$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let the set $W$ consist of the vectors in $\Bbb R^6$ for which it holds that the odd indexed coordinates of them form a geometric sequence with quotient $2$ (from top down), and the even indexed coordinates of them form a geometric sequence with quotient $3$ (from top down). (E.g. the vector $(3, 5, 6, 15, 12, 45)^T$ is in $W$.) Determine the dimension of the subspace $W$.

I tried to figure out and come to conclusion that we can find $2$ vectors which can be bases so we can say dimension${}=2$. However, I think we can find $3,4,5$ such vectors which are independent and dimension can be $3,4,5$. But the answer is $2$. What did I wrong?

Comment: "Dimension van be 3,4,5". A vector space has fixed dimension, it can't have multiple dimensions.... No set of three vectors in $W$ will be independent.

Comment: "I think we can fine 3,4,5...". I'm sorry, but this is not useful. Why do you think that we can find 3 independent vector?

Comment: It is just opinion I havent found yet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A generic vector of $W$ is:
$$(k,t,2k,3t,4k,9t)=k(1,0,2,0,4,0)+t(0,1,0,3,0,9)$$
So $$W=\langle\{(1,0,2,0,4,0),(0,1,0,3,0,9)\}\rangle$$
Clearly those 2 vectors are independent so: $$\dim(W)=2$$
Why do you think there can be 3 independent vectors?

Comment: Thank you. I just didnt know how can I figure out that there cant be 3 or 4 dimension. Now I got it

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** All such vectors can be written as
$$x\pmatrix{1\\0\\2\\0\\3\\0} + y\pmatrix{0\\1\\0\\2\\0\\3}$$
for $x, y\in\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 2):

Intuitively, if you know on odd index and an even index, you automatically know the other indices so there are two degrees of freedom and the dimension is $2$.

More concretely,
$$W= \{(a,b,2a,3b,4a,6b): a,b \in \mathbb{R}\}\cong \mathbb{R}^2$$

An explicit isomorphism is $(a,b) \mapsto (a,b,2a,3b,4a,6b)$
but you can also give an explicit basis for $W$:

$$\{(1,0,2,0,4,0), (0,1,0,3,0,6)\}$$